# How to fix Data limitation error while loading the data from cassandra to powerbi?

Tags: cassandra, powerbi

I am facing the issue with Connector, I am able to pull the data over 4000 records only. If a table having more than that  I am not able to pull the data. I have over 10 millions of records table to pull the data from Cassandra to power bi.

I am able to pull the data which is having below 4000 records. You will find in screenshot.
I am attaching the screenshot of error while loading the table which is having more than 4000 records..

Error : Error while executing the query in cassandra

Comment: error message seems incomplete...

Comment: @Oerd When  i am click on load getting this error in Power BI:  DataSouce error:error[hy000][simba][CassandraODBC](10) error while executing a query in Cassandra: [33559296]:Operation failed-received 0 responses and 1 failures

Comment: sounds like an ODBC issue, try to look at the ODBC config for buffer/cache/memory configurations that you might increase

Comment: @Oerd I tried with 3 different connectors like Simba ODBC Connector, CDATA ODBC connector, and Datastax but getting same issue